# Confused whether to switch from ext2 to ext4 or not

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, filesystems, trim

I recently installed Xubuntu 14.04 on my old laptop and decided to buy an SSD for the new OS. I installed Xubuntu on 32GB ext2 formatted partition because I read that it doesn't have journalling which means lesser writes. It's a 120GB Kingston SSDNow. The reason I didn't partition the whole drive is because I use it as flash storage on my windows via SATA firewire interface. Recently, I read an article that ext2 doesn't suport TRIM but ext4 does(and with DISCARD). But when I issued the command: "sudo fstrim -v /", the next line showed "Freed 12345668 bytes" (I forgot the correct one but it's something like that). Now my question is, should I keep my SSD formatted as ext2 or the more painful ext4 (painful because I have to format it again and SSDs have limited writes) and what are the PROs and CONs of staying or upgrading to a newer filesystem? Which is better at performance and more importantly, life?

Comment: Do you mind (long) file system checks? Do you mind having to reinstall in case fsck is not successful? Are your files valuable and are they difficult to recreate? If you say yes to any of these questions, you should take journalling into consideration.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand the first two questions. I'm just a first time linux user. I say yes to your third question.

Comment: Whether it's `ext2` or `ext3` or `ext4` depends on the feature you enabled. For example, if you run `tune2fs -O has_journal /dev/sdXY` on an ext2 partition, technically it will become ext3. And if you enabled one `ext4` specfic feature (e.g. `extent`), technically it will become ext4. Some of the features are reversible (e.g. `has_journal`), while some are not (e.g. `extent`). Btw `has_journal` is not a "requirement" of `ext4` but only `ext3`.

Comment: It is indeed true that the FITRIM ioctl is only found in `fs/ext4/ioctl.c`, but since now the drivers are pretty much generalized so you can call it on either an ext2/ext3/ext4.

Comment: Whether it's `ext2` or `ext3` or `ext4` depends on the feature you enabled. For example, if you run `tune2fs -O has_journal /dev/sdXY` on an ext2 partition, technically it will become ext3. And if you enabled one `ext4` specfic feature (e.g. `extent`), technically it will become ext4. Some of the features are reversible (e.g. `has_journal`), while some are not (e.g. `extent`). Btw `has_journal` is not a "requirement" of `ext4` but only `ext3`. So you mean I can upgrade to ext4 without repartitioning it? If ext4 has advantges over ext2 then how can I make it ext4? I don't use journalling.

Comment: @ilovemath If your OS crashes for any reason (despite the misbeliefs around linux, it can happen), the inconsistent disk status is fixed with file system check (just like chkdsk in the court of windows). If journalling is there, it's quick(er) and safe. Without journalling, it can last long and the outcome is uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would recommend to use ext4. According to your experience `fstrim` supports not only ext4 but ext2 too; both file systems are equal here. The I/O caused by the ext4 journal is neglectable compared to the I/O caused by the actual data stored on the file system; I would not see a problem with the ext4 journal on a SSD. The ext2 file system misses many ext4 features like [extents, pre-allocation, delayed allocation and multiblock allocators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Features) which all contribute to reduce fragmentation and therefore extend your SSD life.